# How to copy .rmd code chunks into another .rmd?

Tags: copy, r-markdown

I need to automatically move select code chunks from one rmd into another rmd. The current system uses copy/paste but I would like this process to be automated. I tried making the [code chunks into their own R scripts](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/convert-r-markdown-rmd-files-to-r-scripts/) (`knitr::purl`) and then calling those in the second rmd but the code chunks are plots and the figure captions are lost using the `knitr::purl`. Is there an efficient way of copying each code chunk so it is still usable in a second rmd?

Comment: Could you save the RAW file as text and then do string analysis to find three consecutive backticks (representing the start and end of a code chunk)?

Comment: I think my previous answer does not really get to the point. Can you manually add the `fig.cap` hook to the chunk header in the R script after `knit::purl`ing it? I think so, the hook is then imported into the Rmd file along with the chunk code when you use `read_chunk()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to do this, as you will be duplicating code in the process, which may lead to different versions with different up-to-date states. This makes the maintenance of the different Rmd files almost impossible in the long run.
What you probably want to do better is to have an external script with your code chunks, and calling them into the context of you Rmd file with `read_chunk()`:

[Using an external R script with your document](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/externalization/)

This doesn't *exactly* answer your question, but I think it solves your problem.